# On Duplicate Key Update (Non unique field)

Tags: php, mysql, key, duplicates

I'm working on a CSV import script in PHP attached to a MySQL database. I want to give the users the option to either insert new rows if duplicates are found or update them.

I can't use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE because the column cannot be unique, otherwise it won't cater for when they want to have duplicates.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 queries - a select query to determine if the row exists, then based on that result either an insert or update query.

Comment: I was thinking of doing this but is it the most efficient way of doing this? If it's a particularly big file then checking each row to see if it exists seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I would script it for use on the command line. In your loop, check if an entry with the same key already exists. If it does, prompt the user to decide what to do using fgets(STDIN).

Answer (score 0):

why not just add a `UNIQUE` key to the table, possibly spanning multiple fields?
here is an example given the following simple phonebook table:

```
CREATE TABLE phonebook (
    firstname VARCHAR(255),
    lastname VARCHAR(255),
    home VARCHAR(50),
    mobile VARCHAR(50)
)
```

you can easily add a key making firstname AND lastname together unique.

```
ALTER TABLE phonebook ADD UNIQUE (firstname, lastname)
```

that way you can use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement to easily update the phone numbers when the name is already on the list:

```
INSERT INTO phonebook (firstname, lastname, home, mobile) 
VALUES ("john", "doe", "12345", "45678")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE home = "12345", mobile = "45678"
```

everything else is getting unnecessarily complex.